# Adding CVS perspective for eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse

It is not available by default in Windows -> perspective ->other.
As it used to be earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **[CVS Integration](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cvs-integration)** installed. Since the Mars release (2015) Eclipse is no longer shipped with CVS integration as before.